# React Navigation Issue: stacknavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to work my way toward building a drawer navigator using this really nice [tutorial/demo](https://shift.infinite.red/react-navigation-drawer-tutorial-a802fc3ee6dc)

Issue is that although this code works and I can walk through all the screens in my stacknavigator:

```
const navigator = StackNavigator({
  home: { screen: Home },
  signup: { screen: SignUpStep },
  login: { screen: Login },
  selectTeachers: { screen: SelectTeachers },
  dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
},
{
  headerMode: 'float',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#E73536' },
    title: 'You are not logged in',
    headerTintColor: 'white'
  }
});

export default navigator;
```

But when i try to include, as a first step, consolidating the login scenes into a loginstack and then having that as a screen in another const, it does not work:

```
const LoginStack = StackNavigator({
  home: { screen: Home },
  signup: { screen: SignUpStep },
  login: { screen: Login },
  selectTeachers: { screen: SelectTeachers },
  dashboard: { screen: Dashboard },
},
{
  headerMode: 'float',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#E73536' },
    title: 'You are not logged in',
    headerTintColor: 'white'
  }
});

const navigator = StackNavigator({
  loginStack: { screen: LoginStack },
  //drawerStack: { screen: DrawerNavigation }
}, {
  // Default config for all screens
  headerMode: 'none',
  title: 'Main',
  initialRouteName: 'loginStack'
});
export default navigator;
```

here is the error I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The link you brought spread a wrong approach out.

I wrote a comment there,

> Putting drawer under the StackNavigation is a bad idea and it’s not
>   fit with any design guide. In iOS, drag to open action is duplicated
>   with go back action in navigation. In Android, you can find no app
>   from google use this approach. A drawer should cover StackNavigator
>   from outside.

You need to change your second StackNavigator to DrawerNavigator. And see 'react-navigation' documents or example for DrawerNavigator.

Comment: the drawernavigation is commented and thus not active. My concern is that const navigator = StackNavigator({
  loginStack: { screen: LoginStack }, does not work. But it should. I am merely referencing one stacknavigator inside another.

Comment: @SamRao Can you draw some hirachky that you want to archieve? Then I may be able to give some advice.

Comment: @SamRao By the way, I made a working sample for you. https://snack.expo.io/rJIKh61Sf